# PayPal button label missing on "submit-button" button

Tags: paypal

The submit button on my website is blank. It contains no label. Do you know if this is a bug or is there a setting somewhere in paypal? I really searched everywhere, but I could not find it.

This is how it looks like on my website:
[image: How it looks on my website]

And the same happens when I try to setup style on paypal website:
[image]

This is the html for this button:

```
 <button id="submit-button" type="button" class="css-sh6tmc eshn35a0" style="margin-bottom: 18px; margin-top: 18px;"></button>
```

So it's not a problem with CSS but no value is passed. Any ideas? I'm using WooCommerce PayPal checkout plugin, but I don't think it's an issue with the plugin, because the same thing happens on the PayPal website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PayPal bug affecting all European countries at the moment; seems to be missing translation text for that button.

Anyone can reproduce the issue directly at [the integration Demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client), clicking the black button and selecting the flag of a European country.

Update: I've been told this will be fixed in PayPal's next release of the component, whenever that happens